# Resizable layout (by pulling)

Tags: java, android, layout

I have my layout, till moments it works fine, but i want to make the `<ScrollView android:id="@+id/to_Resize"` to be resizeable by pulling it's up and down. Possible i have to add some view, but from this point i don't know which and how to configure it. Anyone have any ideas?
my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"></LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/to_Resize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_block"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:isScrollContainer="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" />
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/PathShow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <GridLayout
            android:id="@+id/pew1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:columnCount="4"
            android:rowCount="12">

        </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```